# How can I add in apache referrer policy header?

Tags: apache-2.4, http-headers

I'm not sure how can I add referrer policy header to my virtual host configuration file.

Let's say that I want to add something like this `Referrer-Header: same-origin`, should it be in this way:

```
Header set Referrer-Header: same-origin
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The header you're looking for is called [`Referrer-Policy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy), not "Referrer-Header".

As such, the correct way to set it would be:

```
Header always set Referrer-Policy "same-origin"
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are asking, or trying to accomplish here...

`SAMEORIGIN` is a value for the `X-Frame-Options` header.

To make `Apache` send this header to all your pages, you would need to add this directive to your site config file :

```
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_headers.html

Comment: Referrer-Policy is different than X-Frame-Options. See: https://www.w3.org/TR/referrer-policy/

Comment: @iglvzx Thank you. I've got it since this post has been published.